# Angular 2 Observable Refresh

Tags: angular

I'm trying to refresh my table at parent after update operation from child component.

@service

```
getLicenses(){
     ...
     return this.http.post(url","",options)
        .map((result: Response) => result.json())
          .map((data: License[]) => {
              this.licenses = data;

              return this.licenses;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

@ parent component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.licenseService.getLicenses().subscribe(licenses => {
                                          this.licenses = licenses;
 });
```

Everything looks good at initialization. I have datas in table.
When a row is selected from table I pass it to child component and do update operation. After update, I want to refresh table and call getLicenses() method of service. But it doesn't refresh.If I call another method to test, it refreshes my table.

```
  getLicenses2(){
    this.licenses.pop();
    this.licenses.pop();
    this.licenses[2].isFree=  !this.licenses[2].isFree;
  }
```

Also I tested like below and this doesn't refresh.

```
  getLicenses2(){

       this.http.post(url,"",options)
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
              .map((data: License[]) => {
                  this.licenses = data;
                  this.licenses.pop();
                  this.licenses.pop();
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Why does this work when I change array manually? 
Why does not work when I assign data of json?

My response is OK there is no exception and first initialization works well.Update operation is succesfull also if I just refresh table with f5 new data is coming.
(I'm new to Angular 2)

**Edit**

It work with or without subject if I just change array but it doesnt work when I do it in http post

I tried with Subject. This time there is no child. Initialization does not work when I call http post. see test methods below.

@service i have

```
private licenses2 = new Subject<License[]>();
licenses2$ = this.licenses2.asObservable();
```

@ parent component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.licenseService.licenses2$.subscribe(licenses => {
        this.licenses = licenses;
     } );
    this.licenseService.getLicenses2();
 }
```

works

```
getLicenses2() {
   let test: License[] = [];
   test.push(new License());

   this.licenses2.next(test)
}
```

doesnt work

```
 getLicenses2(){
   this.http.post(URL,"",options)
        .map(response => {
              this.licenses2.next(response.json() as License[])
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, how do you change the data in the child component and how do you tell the parent about this change? It would be helpful to see the code you use in your child component.

Comment: in child I just call another update service and post new data fields then update database at backend. If return successful I call service.getLicenses() from chield so it will return new updated results as json and update my array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a `Subject`. As from what I understand from your comments, you are trying to update the parent table from the child, and that will not work, since the updates are only present in the child if you do so. So what you can do, is to tell the parent to update the data when you need to do it. So try the following:

Declare a Subject in your parent:

```
public static updateStuff: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and in your parent constructor subscribe:

```
ParentComponent.updateStuff.subscribe(res => {
    // here fire functions that fetch the data from the api
    this.getLicenses(); // add this!
})
```

and in your child component, whenever you make changes that should be updated in parent do this:

```
ParentComponent.updateStuff.next(false);
```

e.g when after doing a post request in your child:

```
// this is the method you call in your child component to do the post request
postChanges() { 
  this.myService.updateTable()
     .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        ParentComponent.updateStuff.next(false); // add this, will update the parent!
  })
}
```

... and then it should work :) Remeber to also unsubscribe :)

Comment: Updated my question. I tired with Subject also. I think problem is different.  I followed this example under Parent and children communicate via a service title.
[link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child)

Comment: Why are you trying to use the subject in the post, don't do that. Do the post in the child normally and then call `ParentComponent.updateStuff.next(false)` which then updates the licenses in the parent :)

Comment: and don't put the Subject in the service, not needed here. Look at my answer. I'll elaborate my answer a bit further.

Comment: Look closely at answer. Declare the subject in parent. After you have made the post request in child, call `ParentComponent.updateStuff.next(false);`

Comment: This plunker does not work, but you can look closer for what I mean with the methods used: http://plnkr.co/edit/qYAkshGhAFnK4QSS9S8I?p=preview

Comment: I dont know why I couldn't think it before :). I didnt do it like you did but i got it when i see your plunker. I just call a service method that notifies parent and tells child changed something. Then parent subscription triggers and gets new licenses, refreshes table. I keep subject in service(because angular.io shows like this). Thank you for your helps. i ll accept this.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it's possible to use the service as well. But I figured this is not necessary in this case, since you actually are not *sharing* any data between the parent and child, the only thing needed here is to tell the parent to update the data. But using the service works just as well and is useful to learn for the future when you actually need to share data between the components! :)